# Identity theorem for a holomorphic funtion defined near zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

I have to show, whether there is a holomorphic funtion $f$ defined in an open neighborhood of zero, such that:
$$ f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=(-1)^n \frac{1}{n^3}$$ for all positive integer $n$.

My idea was to apply the identity theorem for holomorphic funtions.
How can I do that?
Maybe I must consider the subsequences $ \frac{1}{2k}, \frac{1}{2k+1}$. Can somebody help me?

Comment: "f in zero"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I don't know for sure what you want.  This is my guess.  Please change it if it is not what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, Your guess was right:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know clearly what your question is,  I assume you want to find all entire function $f$ such that $f(1/n)=(-1)^n/n^3$ for all positive integers $n$.   I want to point out that $f$ does not exist, and your idea of considering $1/(2k)$ and $1/(2k+1)$ is a good idea.

Note that $f(z)=z^3$ for all $z$ of the form $1/(2k)$ where $k$ is a positive integer.  Since the set of $1/(2k)$ has an accumulation point (namely, $0$) in $\Bbb{C}$, so $f(z)=z^3$ must hold for all $z\in \Bbb{C}$, but then the condition says that $f\big(1/(2k+1)\big)$ is $-1/(2k+1)^3$, not $1/(2k+1)^3$.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:) I dont understand how you get $ f(z)=z^3$ When you consider $1/2k$, then you get $  f(1/2k)= 1/(2k)^3  = \frac{1}{8 z^3 } $?

Comment: If $z=1/(2k)$, then $1/(2k)^3=z^3$.

Comment: Ok, you put  $z=\frac{1}{2k} \Rightarrow g(z)=z^3 $, so  $f(z)=g(z) \forall z=1/2k \Rightarrow f=g$ , but $      f(1/2k+1)= .-1/(2k+1)^3  \ne 1/(2k+1)^3 =g(1/2k+1) $

Comment: Ok I think I understand that now:)

Comment: When i consider another example $ f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{n \frac{1}{n}}{n(1+\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{1}{n})}$ Put $ z=\frac{1}{n}=z$ and define $ g(z)::= \frac{z}{(1-z)(1+z)}  $ , then g(z) is a holomorphic function in z=0, so f=g..

Comment: Is that right? When i apply the Identity theorem, i have to find a function g(z), such that $ I=\{z \in G: f(z)=g(z) \} $ has an accumulation point in G.So for g,f it does hold and z=1/n has an accumulation point in 0. Have I done that right?

Comment: I think something is wrong with your last example.  If $f(1/n)=\frac{1}{n^2-1}$, then $$f(1/n)=\frac{(1/n)^2}{1-(1/n)^2}.$$  Therefore, if $z=1/n$, then $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^2}$.

Comment: Ok sorry:( But f(z) and g(z) are holomorphic functions, especially for z=0, and 1/n has an accumulation point in 0. So there is such a f. Is thar right?

Comment: Yes, in this case, $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^2}$ for every complex number $z$ such that $z\neq \pm 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help:)